# mimic chrome download requests in postman

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I am blocking user's downloads, and I am downloading the files in some other computer (some security app but it's not impotent for the post) based on the download url.

The idea works fine for a lot of cases, for example if user trying to download the file http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf with his chrome browser, the the extension blocks the download, sends the url to some other server and the server downloads the link.

I have problem with websites that asks some headers when downloading the file, is there a way to mimic the exact chrome request from other app?

I tried using `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener` to get all request headers and then to use those headers to download the file from other place (I mean not via chrome but via poatman) and I get Unauthorized

Here a small code example on the bacgroung script:

```
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function (e) {
    console.log(`============= begin onCreated =============`);
    console.log(e);
    console.log(`============= end onCreated =============`);
});
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function (details) {
        console.log(`============= begin onBeforeSendHeaders =============`);
        console.log(details);
        console.log(`============= end onBeforeSendHeaders =============`);
        return {
            requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders
        };
    }, {
        urls: ["<all_urls>"]
    },
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

And when I am trying to download file from LinkedIn I get the output:

```
============= begin onBeforeSendHeaders =============
background.js:27 {frameId: 0, initiator: "https://www.linkedin.com", method: "GET", parentFrameId: -1, requestHeaders: Array(7), …}frameId: 0initiator: "https://www.linkedin.com"method: "GET"parentFrameId: -1requestHeaders: Array(7)0: {name: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", value: "1"}1: {name: "User-Agent", value: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWeb…ML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"}2: {name: "Accept", value: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=…,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"}3: {name: "Sec-Fetch-Site", value: "same-origin"}4: {name: "Sec-Fetch-Mode", value: "navigate"}5: {name: "Sec-Fetch-User", value: "?1"}6: {name: "Sec-Fetch-Dest", value: "document"}length: 7__proto__: Array(0)requestId: "305371"tabId: 844timeStamp: 1596530356040.051type: "main_frame"url: "https://www.linkedin.com/dms/C4D06AQGz1fU0o0r3ZQ/messaging-attachmentFile/0?m=AQLmTdbXe5dgKgAAAXO4axnTdJJLiaU6EnZbq_fhQzg_1697ToPaTbJ3jw&ne=1&v=beta&t=QCDqVeorWfXEAgQBCQdo9hbEQrxwM97zqzCvLuBE2Cw#S6555100544749322240_500"__proto__: Object
background.js:28 ============= end onBeforeSendHeaders =============
background.js:20 ============= begin onCreated =============
background.js:21 {bytesReceived: 0, canResume: false, danger: "safe", exists: true, fileSize: 0, …}bytesReceived: 0canResume: falsedanger: "safe"exists: truefileSize: 0filename: ""finalUrl: "https://www.linkedin.com/dms/D5D06AQGz1fU0o0r3ZK/messaging-attachmentFile/0?m=AQLpTdbXe5dgKgAAAXO4axnTdJJLiaU6EnZbe_fhQzg_1697ToPaTbJ3jw&ne=1&v=beta&t=QCDqVeorWfXEAgQBCQdo9hbEQrxwM97zqzCvLuBE2Cw#S6555100544749322246_500"id: 7100incognito: falsemime: "application/octet-stream"paused: falsereferrer: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/natali-melman-a785a349/"startTime: "2020-08-04T08:39:16.060Z"state: "in_progress"totalBytes: 0url: "https://www.linkedin.com/dms/D5D06AQGz1fU0o0r3ZK/messaging-attachmentFile/0?m=AQLpTdbXe5dgKgAAAXO4axnTdJJLiaU6EnZbe_fhQzg_1697ToPaTbJ3jw&ne=1&v=beta&t=QCDqVeorWfXEAgQBCQdo9hbEQrxwM97zqzCvLuBE2Cw#S6555100544749322256_500"__proto__: Object
background.js:22 ============= end onCreated =============
```

I tried to mimic this exact request in postman (same header, parameters etc) but I get 401 error code

Comment: Add `'extraHeaders'`, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

Comment: @wOxxOm Looks like it work's I will do some tests. but for not it looks good, A HUGE thank you :))))